# How do I convert any ubuntu istallation to a command-line system?

Tags: package-management

On the alternate CD there is the option to install a command-line system. What packages (or meta-packages) are installed when I select this option? What is the easiest way to remove all packages except those and their dependencies (possibly using synaptic or the software centre)?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is certainly to install a new Ubuntu system from the alternate (or minimal) CD, as a command-line only system! However, if you want to know specifically which packages to keep when removing most installed packages to convert a graphical Ubuntu system into a command-line only system, please specify which release of Ubuntu (e.g., 11.10, 11.04) you're interested in doing this on.

Comment: I hoped it would just be a couple of meta-packages and they would be mostly the same for all releases. If they're not I would be grateful for a list for 11.10.

Comment: ssamuel has beat me to the punch with http://askubuntu.com/questions/76857/how-do-i-convert-any-ubuntu-istallation-to-a-command-line-system/76909#76909; that answer has my vote.. The page linked to in that answer is for Ubuntu 11.10 (and has links to the corresponding pages for earlier versions of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is information [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purekde) about how to remove most desktop environments from an Ubuntu installation.

Effectively, that is probably what you want to do: remove all the desktops and X. Once all the desktops are gone, doing a full autoremove should pull all of the dependencies, which should include all of X.